# Trouble using java class within jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I'm trying to use [Java Opencl](http://www.jocl.org/) from within jruby, but am encountering a problem which I can't solve, even with much google searching.

```rb
require 'java'
require 'JOCL-0.1.7.jar'

platforms = org.jocl.cl_platform_id.new
puts platforms.class
org.jocl.CL.clGetPlatformIDs(1, platforms, nil)
```

when I run this code using: jruby test.rb
I get the following error, when the last line is uncommented:

```
#<Class:0x10191777e>
TypeError: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaP
roxy to class [Lorg.jocl.cl_platform_id;
  LukeTest at test.rb:29
    (root) at test.rb:4
```

Just wondering whether anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
ok so I think I've solved the first part of this problem by making platforms an array:

```
platforms = org.jocl.cl_platform_id[1].new
```

but that led to this error when adding the next couple of lines:

```rb
context_properties = org.jocl.cl_context_properties.new()
context_properties.addProperty(org.jocl.CL::CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platforms[0])
```

```
CodegenUtils.java:98:in `human': java.lang.NullPointerException
    from CodegenUtils.java:152:in `prettyParams'
    from CallableSelector.java:462:in `argumentError'
    from CallableSelector.java:436:in `argTypesDoNotMatch'
    from RubyToJavaInvoker.java:248:in `findCallableArityTwo'
    from InstanceMethodInvoker.java:66:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:332:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:203:in `call'
    from test.rb:36:in `module__0$RUBY$LukeTest'
    from test.rb:-1:in `module__0$RUBY$LukeTest'
    from test.rb:4:in `__file__'
    from test.rb:-1:in `load'
    from Ruby.java:679:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:672:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:579:in `runNormally'
    from Ruby.java:428:in `runFromMain'
    from Main.java:278:in `doRunFromMain'
    from Main.java:198:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:164:in `run'
    from Main.java:148:in `run'
    from Main.java:128:in `main'
```

for some reason when I print the class of platforms[0] it's listed as NilClass!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overlooking a very simple mistake. You write

```
platforms = org.jocl.cl_platform_id.new
```

but that line creates a single instance of the class `org.jocl.cl_platform_id`. You then pass that as the second parameter to `org.jocl.CL.clGetPlatformIDs` in

```
org.jocl.CL.clGetPlatformIDs(1, platforms, nil)
```

and that doesn't work, because the second argument of the method requires an (empty) *array* of `org.jocl.cl_platform_id` objects.

What the error says is: "I have something that is a proxy for a Java object and I can't turn it into an an array of `org.jocl.cl_platform_id` objects, as you are asking me to do.

If you just say

```
platforms = []
```

and pass that in, it might just work :).